# Crawling over a website directories using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is my code:
https://pastebin.com/R11qiTF4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re

urls = ["https://www.helios-gesundheit.de"]
domain_list = ["https://www.helios-gesundheit.de/kliniken/schwerin/"]
prohibited = ["info", "news"]
text_keywords = ["Helios", "Helios"]
url_list = []

desired = "https://www.helios-gesundheit.de/kliniken/schwerin/unser-angebot/unsere-fachbereiche-klinikum/allgemein-und-viszeralchirurgie/team-allgemein-und-viszeralchirurgie/"

for x in range(len(domain_list)):
    url_list.append(urls[x]+domain_list[x].replace(urls[x], ""))

print(url_list)

def prohibitedChecker(prohibited_list, string):
    for x in prohibited_list:
        if x in string:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        break

def parseHTML(url):
    requestHTML = req(url)
    htmlPage = requestHTML.read()
    requestHTML.close()
    parsedHTML = soup(htmlPage, "html.parser")
    return parsedHTML

searched_word = "Helios"

for url in url_list:
    parsedHTML = parseHTML(url)
    href_crawler = parsedHTML.find_all("a", href=True)
    for href in href_crawler:
        crawled_url = urljoin(url,href.get("href"))
        print(crawled_url)
        if "www" not in crawled_url:
            continue
        parsedHTML = parseHTML(crawled_url)
        results = parsedHTML.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(searched_word)), recursive=True)
        for single_result in results:
            keyword_text_check = prohibitedChecker(text_keywords, single_result.string)
            if keyword_text_check != True:
                continue
            print(single_result.string)
```

I'm trying to print the contents of ''desired'' variable. The problem is the following, my code doesn't even get to request the URL of ''desired'' because its not in the website scope. ''desired'' href link is inside another href link that's inside the page I'm currently scraping. I thought I'd fix this by adding another for loop inside line 39 for loop, that requests every href found in my first, but this is too messy and not efficient

Is there way to get a list of every directory of a website url?